# The tableview method viewForHeaderInSection is not called - Swift 5 / iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I read every questions concerning this issue and none of the answers solved my issue.

I'm trying to implement a custom header view to my `tableView`. However the method `viewForHeaderInSection` is not called for no reason.

I added the `tableView` datasource and delegate to the `viewController`.

I removed the lines of code the add data to my arrays because it would be too long. Consider my arrays are filled. with some
My code:

```
class TransactionsViewController: UIViewController {
        
        lazy var tableView = UITableView()
        var sections = [TransactionsMonthSection]()
        var transactions = [Transaction]()
        
        // ...
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                
                // adding some data here ...
        
                commonInit()
                tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        private func commonInit() {
                
                view.backgroundColor = .clear
                
                tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
                tableView.rowHeight = 74
                tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50

                tableView.register(TransactionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
                tableView.register(TransactionsHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: TransactionsHeaderView.reuseId)

                tableView.delegate = self
                tableView.dataSource = self

                tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
                tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 32, bottom: 0, right: 16)
                tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
                
                view.addSubview(tableView)
            }
        
}
        
extension TransactionsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
          func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
                
                return self.sections.count
          }
            
            
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                
                return sections[section].transactions.count
          }
        
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? TransactionCell  else {
                    fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TransactionCell.")
                }
                return cell
          }
        
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                
                let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: TransactionsHeaderView.reuseId) as! TransactionsHeaderView
                        
                return header
          }
        
          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                
                return 50
          }
    }
```

The method `heightForHeaderInSection` is called but not `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Also, if I remove this line: `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50`, the method `heightForHeaderInSection` is not called too.

Is that a bug from Xcode? I never seen that before.

Comment: Add some `print()` statements to confirm the functions are *not* being called. In a quick test using the code you posted (with just enough additional to make it run), both `viewForHeaderInSection` and `heightForHeaderInSection` are being called.

Comment: I use prints in my original code and only `heightForHeaderInSection` is called. That's weird.

Comment: I guess it's a bug from Xcode, do you know any way to prevent it ?

Comment: Try running this code https://pastebin.com/CfpXJDXP .. I get `print()` output from both functions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/ Didn't work on iOS 14.4 and Xcode 12.4. I updated to iOS 14.5 and Xcode 12.5 and it still doesn't work...

Comment: I copied and run the exact same code from your pastebin...

Comment: Only `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) 3
tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) 0
tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) 1
tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:) 2`

Comment: Ok I've found why.

Comment: I posted an answer, now I know the reason but I don't really know why and how to bypass this error.

Comment: For future reference, when asking for help it is important to include relevant information -- you hadn't mentioned anything about using this code (or part of it) in a child view controller. Try to put together a [mre].

Comment: The fact that I know why that was happening is the fact that I just remembered that I was doing this. So I couldn't even think about it when writing my question.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the `tableView`'s delegate method `viewForHeaderInSection` wasn't called is because I was adding the `tableView'`s delegate in another `viewController`.

In fact this `TransactionsViewController` is implemented as a child in another `viewController` and I need its delegate there. The issue occurred because I was doing this in the parent VC:

```
transactionsVC.tableView.delegate = self
```

I'm don't really know why it prevents `viewForHeaderInSection` to be called though.